# iconv or mbstring?

Tags: php, iconv, mbstring

Which multibyte-handling library should I use : **iconv** or **mbstring** ?

After some Googling I didn't find enough arguments to convince me to use one particularly, and I could not get any benchmark (and I'm too lazy do create one :-p).

After all maybe this choice doesn't really matters ?

Thanks for any piece of advice.

Comment: mbstring is more safe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375909/iconv-utf-8-ignore-still-produces-illegal-character-error and https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4php/pull/69

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use a combination of both - depending on my needs.
I use iconv to convert from one charset to another, but mbstring for simpler operations like mb_strtoupper() and mb_stristr(). But if only one of the libraries is needed I suggest using mbstring purely for it's widespread functionalities and ease of use.