# What is the difference between iconv() and mb_convert_encoding() in PHP?

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

What's the difference between `iconv()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` in PHP?  Does one perform better, faster, etc. ( eg. with specific encodings )? In what situations would one be preferred over the other?

Here's what I think I know already:

**iconv()**

1. included with most installs of PHP.
2. when characters that can't be mapped to the new character set are found, you can specify if they are converted to a 'similar' character, or ignored.

**mb_convert_encoding()**

1. usually requires installing the php-mbstring extension.
2. is able to handle `HTML-ENTITIES`, converting to and from web hex codes.

Are there other differences?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050754/iconv-or-mbstring

Comment: It can not be said if and when any of those functions will present a problem to you because you didn't share into which *concrete* problems you run. As with any kind of function, it only does a certain job. So you will always run into problems if you use the wrong function for the job.

Comment: This is an on-topic & useful question. The OP did not ask about his specific situation and then fail to provide details to determine the preferred function in his situation; rather, he asked for information on the difference between two PHP functions which appear to perform the same function. Which, of course, begs the question: why do they both exist, and in what situations one would be preferred over the other? This is specific in scope, and broad in applicability (anyone doing character conversions in PHP would want to know this). Question should not have been closed as "not constructive."

Comment: `var_dump(similar_text('iconv','mb_convert_encoding'))` says `4`. So the answer is `4`.

Comment: I agree with Josh... I came here via a Google search, looking for exactly the same information only to be disappointed that the question was rejected. I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @JohnRix, What do you mean by "the question was rejected"?

Comment: @Pacerier, looks like the "closed as not constructive" flag has been removed from the question since.

Comment: [Using mbstring for HTML is deprecated.](https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mbstring-qprint-base64-uuencode-html-entities-deprecated)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`iconv()` is just a wrapper around the `iconv()` function found in the system C library where PHP is running (unless PHP is built with GNU iconv, in which case GNU iconv is used). So the performance and features of `iconv()` depend on where you are running PHP and how it is built.

The implementation of `mb_convert_encoding()`, on the other hand, is included in the PHP (module) source. It includes a library called libmbfl which handles the actual conversion. Thus it works the same regardless of where you're running PHP. There is a list of supported encodings here: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.encodings.php

So, in summary, I guess you could say that `mb_convert_encoding()` is more reliable to use if you want to support different platforms. However, if you use `iconv()` on Linux (for example), then it supports a lot more encodings (see `iconv --list`).

The relative performance of the functions also depends on the specific `iconv()` implementation, obviously.

Comment: [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) have `//TRANSLIT` and `//IGNORE` options to deal with non-convertable characters.. read the [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) comments for `//IGNORE` problems which will make your code throw E_NOTICE errors. [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) can only remove invalid characters with `ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character','none');` (see [mbstring.substitute_character](http://php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.configuration.php))

Comment: @Sanya_Zol True, but that is because you are using glibc's iconv() implementation. In theory it could work differently on other platforms as [POSIX doesn't define which codesets are available](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv_open.html).

Comment: `iconv -l` for windows

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.4 there is a bug.
Sometime iconv returns null string instead of returning a string with 'similar' char.

So you should use mb_convert_encoding.

Comment: link at this bug would be helpful

Comment: I don't think it was ever PHP 5.4 bug. We had this when moving app between production servers, there were differences caused by different `iconv` versions on each host machine.