PHP MySql problem with special charater from different encoded table
I have a php script that copies data from 1 table to another.
The source table and its fields are utf8mb4_general_ci while the target table and its fields are utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
I get an "Incorrect string value" each time the script tries to insert a special characte like "è".
The DataBase version is 8.0.36-28. The script used to wok well with  5.6.51-91.0-log DB version.
I tryed with and without mb_convert_encoding, the result is the same.

There is an answer about this that is recommended by the PHP Collective: UTF-8 all the way through. It might contain useful information, or at least give you an idea which information is missing from your question.

You haven't asked a question, or presented any code.

Might help . Taken from @KIKOSoftware UTF-8 all the way through

@Bill Karwin
Since I wrote that I get an "Incorrect string value" I think the question does not need to be written. I simply want to avoid the error.

utf8mb4_general_ci and utf8mb4_unicode_ci are different _COLLATIONs_ of the same encoding -- utf8mb4.
If you are bringing the data into PHP and then sending it back out, the likely villain is found in SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';  Please run that and show us the result.
The best fix is to connect with utf8mb4; second best is to run SET NAMES utf8mb4; right after connecting.
mb_convert_encoding (and any other conversion tool) will only make things worse.
Simply using SQL to migrate the data may be better:
INSERT INTO new_table
    SELECT * FROM old_table;

or
INSERT INTO new_table (col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM old_table;

The latter syntax lets you add/remove columns (etc) at the same time as you copy the data.  However, any expressions may involve the COLLATION and cause trouble.
Let's see your "copy" code.

Different encoding can be a real pain.
And confusing.
I advise you to have a look at iconv(). it can change encoding1 to encoding2:
iconv
Or, if you want to dive a bit deeper, follow the link by KIKO software in the comment.

Thank you for the suggestion. Does iconv() behave differently from mb_convert_encoding()? I checked the documentation but the description is the same.

Not a lot of difference between them too: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233517/what-is-the-difference-between-iconv-and-mb-convert-encoding-in-php
