# iconv UTF-8//IGNORE still produces "illegal character" error

Tags: php, utf-8, iconv

```
$string = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $string);
```

I thought this code would remove invalid UTF-8 characters, but it produces `[E_NOTICE] "iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string"`. What am I missing, how do I properly strip a string from illegal characters?

Comment: May this answer help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/70471943

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The output character set (the second parameter) should be different from the input character set (first param).  If they are the same, then if there are illegal UTF-8 characters in the string, `iconv` will reject them as being illegal according to the input character set.

Comment: Do you propose a solution? I've actually [read](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2005/01/24/how-to-get-rid-of-invalid-utf-8-characters.html) [that](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#78972) this should work

Comment: Yes, I've seen that link, but have a look at this https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/261.  My understanding is that iconv doesn't do input encoding now - but I could be wrong. The link above also has a link to an alternative solution, which is at https://gist.github.com/1262496.

Comment: That makes sense. I will first try `mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8", "UTF-8")`, and if it doesn't work out I'll try the gist. Thanks!

Comment: also note that iconv relies on locale being set correctly, so make sure you call setlocale(..); with the appropriate value first. Depending on the locale, the output will be different.

Comment: I don't have my code in front of me right now, but I'm pretty sure `iconv()` will allow it if you just specify one of the encodings as UCS

Answer (score 2):

I know 2 methods how to fix UTF-8 string containing illegal characters:

1. Illegal characters will be replaced by question marks ("?"):

`$message = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');`

2. Illegal characters will be removedL

`$message = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $message);`

The second method actually was described in question. But it doesn't produce any `E_NOTICE` in my case. I tested with different corrupted UTF-8 strings with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and always result was as expected. Possible something was changed since 2012. I tested on PHP 7.2.9 Win.

Answer (score 1):

I am using mb_convert_encoding with bellow setting which removes the invalid character

```
ini_set('mbstring.substitute_character', "none");
$string= mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

it is working in my case.Earlier I was getting below notice

> Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to` UTF-8//IGNORE' is not allowed

```
$string= iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string)
```

Answer (score -1):

To simply ignore notice, you can use "@":

`$string = @iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $string);`

Comment: The string returned then is empty

Comment: You shouldn't do that, because in some cases you can obtain empty string.