# Using iconv() to check for invalid UTF-8 characters: Detected an illegal character in input string

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using iconv() to check if a string contains non-valid UTF-8 characters.

```
$valid = $string == iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
```

However, this still throws the error: "iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string"

To the best of my knowledge this should not be possible using the //IGNORE flag?

I'm using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iconv UTF-8//IGNORE still produces "illegal character" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375909/iconv-utf-8-ignore-still-produces-illegal-character-error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9375952/3000068) provides a better answer for why `iconv()` is throwing an error:

> The output character set (the second parameter) should be different
>   from the input character set (first param). If they are the same, then
>   if there are illegal UTF-8 characters in the string, iconv will reject
>   them as being illegal according to the input character set.

[Taken from a comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php#102510) in the PHP manual, you can detect if a string is encoded in UTF-8 with this function:

```
 $valid = mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true); // returns boolean.
```

More [info on mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php);

Comment: Deleted my other comment on the question because this _is_ working quite well after I _actually changed the encoding on the string I was testing_. Posted an answer as it's more canonical for than two separate links (and the dupe doesn't _technically_ solve the problem of checking for UTF-8 encoded strings - just explains why `iconv()` doesn't work)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!