# Why does iconv returns empty string in php:7.4-fpm-alpine docker

Tags: php, docker, encoding, character-encoding, iconv

Given the following code:

```php
<?php
$mb_name = "湊崎 紗夏";
$tmp_mb_name = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $mb_name);
if($tmp_mb_name != $mb_name) {
    echo "tmp_mb_name: {$tmp_mb_name}\n";
    echo "mb_name: {$mb_name}\n";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "no problem!\n";
}
```

I tested in [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/0qAEt) and it outputs `no problem!`

However, in `php:7.4-fpm-alpine docker` image, it outputs the following:

```
tmp_mb_name: 
mb_name: 湊崎 紗夏
```

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php):

> If you append the string //IGNORE, characters that cannot be represented in the target charset are silently discarded.

Why does `$mb_name` cannot be represented in `UTF-8` in php alpine image?

Comment: Have you gone through https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php ?

Comment: [Are you sure it's not a config problem with your machine?](https://3v4l.org/0eLEm) Also what does this code supposedly _do_?

Comment: @Sammitch It should output `no problem!`

Comment: @Sammitch What config should I do?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1);` and you'll see `Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from 'UTF-8' to 'UTF-8//IGNORE' is not allowed in /test.php on line 5` because apparently [the alpine images just constantly have problems with iconv](https://github.com/nunomaduro/phpinsights/issues/43).

Comment: Also why are you converting to/from the same charset? What is this supposed to accomplish other than verifying that iconv is broken?

Comment: @Sammitch It's not my code. The original dev thought it'd be good to use iconv for validation. Maybe inspired by [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#78972)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `error_reporting(-1);` and you'll see:

> Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from 'UTF-8' to 'UTF-8//IGNORE' is not allowed in /test.php on line 5

Because apparently [the alpine images just don't work properly with iconv](https://github.com/nunomaduro/phpinsights/issues/43) and [the maintainers have simply given up on actually fixing it](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240#issuecomment-353678474). I think that it is important to note here that PHP does not provide *any* official docker images, these are "Docker Official" images for PHP that are maintained by the docker community.

If you don't mind somewhat larger base images just switch to a not-alpine image.

**Edit:** Yes the [noted workaround](https://github.com/nunomaduro/phpinsights/issues/43#issuecomment-498108857) does seem to work. For the sake of not leaving useful information behind a link, example Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-alpine

# fix work iconv library with alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php
```

example build:

```
docker build -t php:7.4-alpine-iconv ./
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To change provider of the php-fpm image from alpine to php.net worked for me.

Dockerfile example:

```
Original:
FROM php:${VERSION}-fpm-alpine 
Edited:
FROM php:${VERSION}-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `alpine:3.14` base image, you can just install the following package https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=php7-iconv&branch=v3.14

Comment: Actually the package doesn't seem to do anything, which is a bit confusing, not sure what the purpose of it is then.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing `php7-mbstring` `php7-iconv` in that order

```sh
RUN apk --no-cache add php7-mbstring php7-iconv
```

Original solution here: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240#issuecomment-355489551

Answer (score 0):

## Finally i solve it in PHP8

**after try a lot of different methods**

```
docker pull php:8.0.14-cli-alpine3.15

docker run -dit --name myphp php:8.0.14-cli-alpine3.15

docker exec -it --user root myphp ash
```

Now we are in the container :

```
apk add --no-cache --virtual .b $PHPIZE_DEPS curl-dev openssl-dev pcre-dev pcre2-dev zlib-dev wget build-base php8-dev nano

apk add --no-cache --repository https://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ gnu-libiconv-dev

mv /usr/bin/gnu-iconv /usr/bin/iconv

mv /usr/include/gnu-libiconv/*.h /usr/include

rm -fr /usr/include/gnu-libiconv

mkdir -p /tmp/q

cd /tmp/q

wget https://secure.php.net/distributions/php-8.0.14.tar.gz

tar xzf php-8.0.14.tar.gz

cd php-8.0.14/ext/iconv

phpize

./configure --with-iconv=/usr
```

## ERROR

`configure: error: iconv does not support errno`
**Try solve it :**

```
nano configure
```

Now remove "else" block (that contains `iconv does not support errno` error message)

## Continue

```
./configure --with-iconv=/usr

make

make install

mkdir -p /etc/php8/conf.d

echo "extension=iconv.so" > /etc/php8/conf.d/iconv.ini

apk del .b

cd

rm -fr /tmp/q
```

## Test

```
php -m | grep iconv

php -i | grep iconv

php -r 'echo iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE","A\xe9 B"),PHP_EOL;'
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP5.6.40 and Alpine3.8**

Quite an old post with answers, but since there is no answer covering older version of `PHP` and `alpine linux` I will post how I fixed it.

1/ Download the php extension `.so` file from `alpine3.13` (since it does not exists for the next version, and some old version like the alpine3.8)

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/out:/out -it alpine:3.13 \\n/bin/sh -c 'apk add --no-cache gnu-libiconv && cp -f /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so /out/preloadable_libiconv.so'
```

You should find the `*.so` file in your local /out/ directory.

2/ Add the file to your image in your `Dockerfile` and preload it with php

```
COPY your/file/previously/downloaded/path/preloadable_libiconv.so /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php
```

You should not have the error anymore.

The credit goes to this guy **@doublesharp** that found the solution on his blog: [Alpine Linux PHP + iconv fix](https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/linux/alpine-linux-php-iconv-fix/)